Copy Adjacent cell if a cell value equal any cell value in the range
I'm working on a range of columns from G:N to register cleints names and phone number adjacent to the name as show in the flowing MD
The client name maybe repeated more than one time in the range and what I need to do is to have a vba code to copy the phone number of the client to the next adjacent cell if the name was repeated before at any one of the four name columns ("G-I-K-M").....
Unfortunately I couldn't solve it with xlookup or else formula because in case if there is no match in the range then I have to insert the phone number manually and this overrides the formula in the cell and stop it to expand in the new row and I have to copy the formula again every time to the new cell
looking for your professional help please.

If you have a list of all clients and phone numbers, a VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH could do this for you

@cybernetic.nomad Unfortunately this is not possible because in case if the client name is new then I have to insert the phone number manually and this will stop the formula to expand in the new row

@cybernetic please note that if I put a formula in a cell and there was no match then I have to write the phone number manually and this will override the formula in the cell which will stop it to expand in the new row in the table when entering a new record - If I know how to create a code to solve my probelm I wouldn't have to ask for help - so if you can help this will be appreciated , otherwise thank you


Right-click on the sheet tab, select View Code and paste the code into the code window

Microsoft documentation:

Application.Intersect method (Excel)


Application.Union method (Excel)


Worksheet.Change event (Excel)

Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const START_ROW = 5
    Const COL_NAME_FIRST = 7 ' Col G
    Const CNT_NAME = 4
    With Target
        If .CountLarge > 1 Or .Row < START_ROW Or Len(.Cells(1).Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Dim rngName As Range, i As Long, rngCol As Range
        Set rngName = Me.Columns(COL_NAME_FIRST)
        For i = 1 To CNT_NAME - 1
            Set rngName = Union(rngName, Me.Columns(COL_NAME_FIRST).Offset(, i * 2))
        Next
        If Application.Intersect(Target, rngName) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set rngName = Intersect(rngName, Me.UsedRange)
        For Each rngCol In rngName.Columns
            Dim vRes: vRes = Application.Match(.Value, rngCol, 0)
            If Not IsError(vRes) Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Offset(, 1) = rngCol.Offset(, 1).Cells(vRes)
                Application.EnableEvents = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub




thank you so much for your professional answer I do appreciate it and actually it works very good but not for all cells I don't know whats wrong - I mean when I tested some names I got the phone number directly in the adjacent cell while some other names I got nothing... all my cells have the same formating in phone number as text as you can see in the attached screenshot  - https://files.fm/u/yprs9kq3fg  .... is there is any sugesstions to do in my sheet?

now it's not working at all

I've tested the code without issues. Please edit your post to share sample data.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator

MD table attached to my question in english text

I haven't seen it.

ok fixed - thank you anyway for your help
